# Pass keyword argument only to __new__() and never further it to __init__()?

Tags: python, mocking

## **Part 1**

I have a setup where I have a set of classes that I want to mock, my idea was that in the cases where I want to do this I pass a `mock` keyword argument into the constructor and in `__new__` intercept this and instead pass back a mocked version of that object.

It looks like this (**Edited the keyword lookup after @mgilsons suggestion**):

```
class RealObject(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.pop('mock', None):
            return MockRealObject()
        return super(RealObect, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, whatever = None):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        #stuff happens
```

I then call the constructor like this:

```
ro = RealObject(mock = bool)
```

The issue I have here is that I get the following error when `bool` is `False`:

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mock'`

This works if I add `mock` as a keyword argument to `__init__` but what I am asking if this is possible to avoid. I even pop the `mock` from the `kwargs` `dict`.

This is *also* a question about the design. Is there a better way to do this? (of course!) I wanted to try doing it this way, without using a factory or a superclass or anything. But still, should I use another keyword maybe? `__call__`?

## **Part 2 based on jsbueno's answer**

So I wanted to extract the metaclass and the `__new__` function into a separate module. I did this:

```
class Mockable(object):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):

        if kwargs.pop('mock', None):
            mock_cls = eval('{0}{1}'.format('Mock',cls.__name__))
            return super(mock_cls, mock_cls).__new__(mock_cls)

        return super(cls, cls).__new__(cls,*args, **kwargs)


class MockableMetaclass(type):

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.__new__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if "mock" in kwargs:
            del kwargs["mock"]

        obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        return obj
```

And I have defined in a separate module the classes `RealObject` and `MockRealObject`. 
I have two problems now:

1. If `MockableMetaclass` and `Mockable` are not in the same module as the `RealObject` class the `eval` will raise a `NameError` if I provide `mock = True`.
2. If `mock = False` the code will enter into an endless recursion that ends in an impressive `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python objec`. I'm guessing this is due to `RealObject`'s superclass no longer being `object` but instead `Mockable`.

How can I fix these problems? is my approach incorrect? Should I instead have `Mockable` as a decorator? I tried that but that didn't seem to work since `__new__` of an instance is only read-only it seems.

Comment: Try `kwargs = kwargs.pop('mock')` instead.

Comment: `dict.pop()` returns the popped object as far as I know

Comment: My mistake, you are correct.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a job for the metaclass!  :-)

The code responsible to call both `__new__` and `__init__` when instantiating a Python new-style object lies in the `__call__`method for the class metaclass. (or the semantically equivalent to that).

In other words - when you do:

`RealObject()`  - what is really called is the `RealObject.__class__.__call__` method.
Since without declaring a explicit metaclass, the metaclass is `type`, it is `type.__call__` which is called.

Most recipes around dealing with metaclasses deal with subclassing the `__new__` method - automating actions when the class is created. But overriding `__call__` we can take actions when the class is instantiated, instead.

In this case, all that is needed is to remove the "mock" keyword parameter, if any, before calling `__init__`:

```
class MetaMock(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
       obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
       if "mock" in kw:
           del kw["mock"]
       obj.__init__(*args, **kw)
       return obj

class RealObject(metaclass=MetaMock):
    ...
```

Comment: Yep, I thought it would be something like this.

Comment: I like this approach, but I have edited my question and added a question about how to extract these so that I can avoid code duplication. Please have a look!

Comment: @parham: Pydev is wrong - this is a metaclass, and its instances are "the class - calling the first parameter as "self" leads to human confusion - it is a convention, withch is held for ordinary classes. If you need it to be self because of broken lint tools you are using, keep the changes on your side - here we are looking at the code on the web, and there is no pylint. Indeed - `__new__` should receive the first arg - the_ which should be _cls_ - not _self_  or got o Google and try to find `__new__` getting something called "self"  as first parameter anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

A subclass is pretty much essential, since `__new__` always passes the arguments to the constructor call to the `__init__` method.  If you add a subclass via a class decorator as a mixin then you can intercept the `mock` argument in the subclass `__init__`:

```
def mock_with(mock_cls):
    class MockMixin(object):
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            if kwargs.pop('mock'):
                return mock_cls()
            return super(MockMixin, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            kwargs.pop('mock')
            super(MockMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def decorator(real_cls):
        return type(real_cls.__name__, (MockMixin, real_cls), {})
    return decorator

class MockRealObject(object):
    pass

@mock_with(MockRealObject)
class RealObject(object):
    def __init__(self, whatever=None):
        pass

r = RealObject(mock=False)
assert isinstance(r, RealObject)
m = RealObject(mock=True)
assert isinstance(m, MockRealObject)
```

The alternative is for the subclass `__new__` method to return `RealObject(cls, *args, **kwargs)`; in that case, since the returned object isn't an instance of the subclass.  However in that case the `isinstance` check will fail.