# Subclassing `Process` to set process level constant

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to subclass `mp.Process` to create process level constant to decide between GPUs on my desktop. To achieve this, I'd like to have a device id inside each process object and later pass it to a function in `run` method. The example code here does not actually yet use `self._gpu_id` and does without error handling, but attempts to create subclassed process with a `gpu_id`.

[From](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755754/pass-keyword-argument-only-to-new-and-never-further-it-to-init) I attempted

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from typing import Type

# Attempt to override default behaviour of the `Process`
# to add a gpu_id parameter during construction.
class GPUProcessMeta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        gpu_id = cls.next_id
        if gpu_id in cls.used_ids:
            raise RuntimeError(
                f"Attempt to reserve reserved processor {gpu_id} {cls.used_ids=}"
            )
        cls.next_id += 1
        cls.used_ids.append(gpu_id)
        kwargs["gpu_id"] = gpu_id
        obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return obj

class GPUProcess(mp.Process, metaclass=GPUProcessMeta):
    used_ids: list[int] = []
    next_id: int = 0

    def __init__(
        self,
        group=None,
        target=None,
        name=None,
        args=(),
        kwargs={},
        *,
        daemon=None,
        gpu_id=None,
    ):
        super(GPUProcess, self).__init__(
            group,
            target,
            name,
            args,
            kwargs,
            daemon=daemon,
        )
        self._gpu_id = gpu_id

    @property
    def gpu_id(self):
        return self._gpu_id

    def __del__(self):
        GPUProcess.used_ids.remove(self.gpu_id)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"<{type(self)} gpu_id={self.gpu_id} hash={hash(self)}>"

    @classmethod
    def create_gpu_context(cls) -> Type[mp.context.DefaultContext]:
        context = mp.get_context()
        context.Process = cls
        return context

def test_gpu_pool():    
    ctx = GPUProcess.create_gpu_context()
    with ctx.Pool(2) as pool:
        payload = (tuple(range(3)) for _ in range(10))
        response = pool.starmap(
            _dummy_func,
            payload,
        )
    assert response == ((0, 1, 2),) * 10

def _dummy_func(*args, **kwargs):
    return args, kwargs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_gpu_pool()
```

However, this crashes with `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. I do not understand what could cause this. How can I create this implementation `Process` with a unique process level variable?

EDIT: After some digging to python [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bd2ed066c855dadbc739e89f9bc32e218dfc904e/Lib/multiprocessing/context.py#L220)

```
#
# Type of default context -- underlying context can be set at most once
#

class Process(process.BaseProcess):
    _start_method = None
    @staticmethod
    def _Popen(process_obj):
        return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)

    @staticmethod
    def _after_fork():
        return _default_context.get_context().Process._after_fork()
```

Where `_POpen` causes call to `_POpen` with infinite recursion and crashes my code. I am not sure how `GPUProcess` can differ from standard `Process` but the root for the crash is here.

Comment: What do you mean with "unique process level variable"; what's your actual end goal here, if we don't talk about the method to achieve it? (The id won't automagically be propagated to the subprocess anyway...)

Comment: @AKX it will eventually be passed as a constant parameter to a function given to this Process. I saw no point in actually attempting to do this, as the class has an error. Eg. I have two gpus and like to have two processes handling a large payload. This parameter would spesify the used device.

Comment: I'm not following why you need this magic at all – just pass the ID as a kwarg..?

Comment: @AKX that approach may lead to a `CUDAAllocationError` as a both processes could potentially attempt to use the same device. I might not understand your approach.

Comment: Avoid metaclasses where possible, and in this case you can avoid it by defining a base class with an appropriate `__init_subclass__` method.

Comment: @chepner Does this mean that I should move my `gpu_id` fetch logic to a function which I would assign with `Process.__init_subclass__ = <this function>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class targets a `mp.Process` which is a proxy for the current context `Process`. This leads to jumps in underlying `multiprocessing` implementation eventually crashing the program with `RecursionError`.

Correct inheritance should be implemented with

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from typing import Type

class GPUProcess(mp.get_context().Process):
    used_ids: list[int] = []
    next_id: int = 0

    def __init__(
        self,
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__(
            *args,
            **kwargs,
        )
        gpu_id = GPUProcess.next_id
        if gpu_id in GPUProcess.used_ids:
            raise RuntimeError(
                f"Attempt to reserve reserved processor {gpu_id} {self.used_ids=}"
            )
        GPUProcess.next_id += 1
        GPUProcess.used_ids.append(gpu_id)
        self._gpu_id = gpu_id

    @property
    def gpu_id(self):
        return self._gpu_id

    def __del__(self):
        GPUProcess.used_ids.remove(self.gpu_id)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"<{type(self)} gpu_id={self.gpu_id} hash={hash(self)}>"

    @classmethod
    def create_gpu_context(cls) -> Type[mp.context.DefaultContext]:
        context = mp.get_context()
        context.Process = cls
        return context

def test_gpu_pool():    
    ctx = GPUProcess.create_gpu_context()
    with ctx.Pool(2) as pool:
        payload = (tuple(range(3)) for _ in range(3))
        response = pool.starmap(
            _dummy_func,
            payload,
        )
    assert response == (
        expected := list(
            (
                (
                    (0, 1, 2),
                    {},
                ),
            )
            * 3
        )
    ), f"{response=}!={expected}"

def _dummy_func(*args, **kwargs):
    return args, kwargs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_gpu_pool()
```

Ref [cpython issue #103645](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/103645#issuecomment-1516070598)

This code is not optimal and `set` could be used as id instead of list, but the overall idea is implemented here.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you actually want [`multiprocessing` shared memory](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#module-multiprocessing.shared_memory) to coordinate which subprocess can access a given GPU.

Here's a simple toy example where 4 processes with 10 jobs to do compete over 2 GPUs. It uses a lock and a shared memory array; each process marks itself as the owner of a given GPU by writing its PID into the first free "slot" of the GPU array.

For a more production-ready example, you would need to add some error tolerance (e.g. ensure the workers always release their GPUs, etc.)

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import random
import time
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class SharedVariables:
    gpu_pool_lock: multiprocessing.Lock
    gpu_array: multiprocessing.Array

    def get_free_gpu(self):
        with self.gpu_pool_lock:
            for gpu_id, pid in enumerate(self.gpu_array):
                if pid == 0:
                    self.gpu_array[gpu_id] = os.getpid()
                    return gpu_id
            return None

    def release_gpu(self, gpu_id):
        with self.gpu_pool_lock:
            assert self.gpu_array[gpu_id] == os.getpid()
            self.gpu_array[gpu_id] = 0


shared_variables: SharedVariables


def init_worker(shv: SharedVariables):
    global shared_variables
    shared_variables = shv


def do_work(x):
    print(f"Worker {os.getpid()} starting work {x}")
    gpu_id = None
    while gpu_id is None:
        gpu_id = shared_variables.get_free_gpu()
        time.sleep(0.5)
    print(f"Worker {os.getpid()} got gpu {gpu_id}")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(2, 4))
    shared_variables.release_gpu(gpu_id)
    print(f"Worker {os.getpid()} released gpu {gpu_id}")
    time.sleep(0.5)


def main():
    num_gpus = 2
    shared_variables = SharedVariables(
        gpu_pool_lock=multiprocessing.Lock(),
        gpu_array=(multiprocessing.Array("i", [0] * num_gpus)),
    )
    with multiprocessing.Pool(
        4,
        initializer=init_worker,
        initargs=(shared_variables,),
    ) as pool:
        res = [pool.apply_async(do_work, args=(x,)) for x in range(10)]
        while not (all(r.ready() for r in res)):
            print("Main: GPUs in use:", shared_variables.gpu_array[:])
            time.sleep(0.5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

An example output would be

```
Main: GPUs in use: [0, 0]
Worker 41543 starting work 0
Worker 41542 starting work 1
Worker 41541 starting work 2
Worker 41544 starting work 3
Main: GPUs in use: [41543, 41542]
Worker 41543 got gpu 0
Worker 41542 got gpu 1
Main: GPUs in use: [41543, 41542]
Main: GPUs in use: [41543, 41542]
Main: GPUs in use: [41543, 41542]
Main: GPUs in use: [41543, 41542]
Main: GPUs in use: [41543, 41542]
Worker 41542 released gpu 1
Main: GPUs in use: [41543, 0]
Worker 41542 starting work 4
Worker 41543 released gpu 0
Main: GPUs in use: [0, 41544]
Worker 41544 got gpu 1
Worker 41543 starting work 5
Main: GPUs in use: [41541, 41544]
Worker 41541 got gpu 0
Main: GPUs in use: [41541, 41544]
```

etc.

Comment: This is a cool solution! I was just wondering whether it'd be optimal to actually have each process access only one gpu. Then this type of common memory access would not be necessary and all processes would be independent of each other.